# Bootstrap - Refresh all tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I am having `3 tabs` & on `click event` & bring data from `ajax` & fill it in 3 tabs.

What happens is that tab which is `currently active` & which can be seen fills the new data in tab, when i click on any other tab, the old data is seen.

How to `refresh` the tabs, so that new data can be seen?

Comment: Use it Where ever you want `location.reload();`

Comment: This will reload the whole page, which is not required in my case..!

Comment: please provide some code example of what you got so far so we can help

Comment: 404. sample code not found